# Splitting pages within a PDF with ArcoJS / Acrobat JS with a given array of names

Tags: acrobat

So, I am super new to using the JS interface within Acrobat and I am trying to write something for splitting PDF pages easily to an array of file names. I cannot find a lot of snippets around that seems to show me how to work with Acrobat JS. Can you provide some guidance on how a script similar to such will look like and how I can execute it within Acrobat? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need Acrobat Professional or Standard for JS tasks generally. And you will execute code like you do within your normal terminal/immediates window within what they call the `debugger` tool for Javascript. You will need to first activate JS within Acrobat by going to `Preferences` and activate the `Debugger`. After you set the preferences, restart Acrobat, and find the tools for the Javascript debugger (different places based on your version, google it if you can't find it).

Once you get the debugger running, run the code below after modifying for the file names you wish to use and the appropriate file paths. Then highlight the entire code block and hit `Ctrl`+`Enter` and it will automatically split the pages for you. Enjoy.

```
Split();

function Split() {
    var totalPages = this.numPages; 
    var i;
    var arrNames = [ "SOME ARRAY" ];
    var targetPath  = "/C/Users/...SOMEPATH/";

    try { 
        for (i = 0; i  < totalPages; i++) {
            this.extractPages({
            nStart: i,
            cPath: targetPath +arrNames[i] + ".pdf"
        }); 

        console.println("Completed: " + targetPath + arrNames[i] + ".pdf");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.println("Aborted: " + e);
    }
 }
```